# How can I make 'Santon sauce'

Tags: sauce, chinese-cuisine, food-identification, chili-peppers

My local Chinese restaurant (Happy Chef on King St, Sydney for anyone who's interested) does a very simple dish of a half crispy skin chicken, served with rice and a sauce that they call 'Santon sauce'. It's the most ludicrously tasty sauce I've come across, but I have no idea what the magic ingredients are. Here's what I know:

- It's about the consistency of, say, fish sauce or wine.
- It's a clear, pinkish red, about the colour and transparency you'd expect from a red wine vinegar.
- It's quite sweet, a bit sour, moderately salty.
- The non liquid ingredients are shredded chillies (which have probably soaking in the sauce for a while as far as I can see), shredded coriander (cillantro) and sliced spring onion (scallions).
- It has a strong, almost pungent taste which I think comes from something other than the chillies (although they undoubtedly contribute).
- I have a reasonably decent knowledge of oriental flavours, but there is at least one flavour component which I'm completely unable to identify, or even say what it's similar to (not helpful I know!). I think it's some sort of herb or spice, which does something similar to fenugreek in terms of its flavour curve (lots of presence in the aroma, initial taste, slow fade).

Santon sauce appears to be just a name used by this particular restaurant; I can't find reference to anything similar online. Does anyone recognise it or have any suspicions?

Ingredients it might contain:

- Sweet rice wine
- Rice wine vinegar
- Fish sauce?

Ingredients it probably doesn't contain:

- Soy

Comment: Any chance at all of a photo?

Comment: I'll take one next time I'm in there, but I'm afraid it won't be very illuminating: just a red-ish clear liquid with coriander, spring onion and chillies floating in it.

Comment: Even so, it'll help. It may not suggest what *is* in the sauce, but it may help us to avoid chasing red herrings. Another thing that might help is to get others to describe what *they* taste. A single descriptive word could be key to the puzzle. One last suggestion I offer is to bribe the bartender (or busboy).

Comment: Agreed - I'll reply with a picture as soon as I can. As for your other method, I already tried to get the staff to divulge the secret, but alas they remain tight-lipped! :-/

Comment: Your description of the strong, almost pungent taste makes me think fish sauce. It sounds like it might be a variation of the vietnamese dipping sauce Nuoc Cham. How thick is the sauce? Nuoc Cham is very thin, no thicker than water. http://www.vietworldkitchen.com/blog/2008/11/basic-vietnamese-dipping-sauce-nuoc-cham.html

Comment: @HenrikSoderlund: There could be fish sauce in there, but if there is, it's quite subtle - there just for seasoning rather than a key flavour component.

Comment: Does it taste like plum or citrus? This dish (crispy chicken) is presumably from where I come from - we often dip it in plum sauce and/or spiced salt.

Comment: @xuq01 I don't _think_ so - if there is a fruit component, it's not a fruit I've tasted before

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you have described it sounds like Santon sauce may be a variation of Shandong sauce which is often served in Chinese restaurants alongside Crispy Skin Chicken. Here is a basic recipe that can be found on many internet sites. Perhaps it can be a starting point for you.

2 garlic cloves, finely chopped
2 chilies, finely chopped (I finely strip them rather than chop)
2 scallions, finely chopped (I thinly slice them)
1 tsp sugar
1 tsp sesame oil (I always use the light version)
2 1/2 Tbl chicken stock
Pinch of MSG
3 tsp dry sherry
2 tsp wine vinegar

- Heat a wok and add the garlic, chilies, onions, sugar, and sesame oil. Stir fry for 1 minute. Then add the chicken stock, MSG, sherry and vinegar.
- Bring to a boil and then simmer for 20 seconds.

I have found that the flavor varies depending on the type of chilies, sherry, and vinegar used. You can try different types of each to get the particular flavor profile you are looking for.

If you try this and get the taste you want I would be interested to know the final ingredients.

Comment: Oooh... "Santon"/ "Shandong" I think maybe you're on to something!

Comment: Yes, the name are hopefully too similar for it to be a coincidence! I will try this recipe asap and let you know how it turns out. If it *is* the right one, it's unfortunate for me as I will have lost the argument I was having with my friend about where this unidentifiable flavour comes from: he says it's the type of chilli, I say there's something else to it. Looks like he might be right! What's the typical variety of chilli you use when you make this? Is there a particular variety which could impart this unusual extra flavour?

Comment: That recipe doesn't call for cilantro, which could be the missing ingredient behind the pungent flavor you describe.  A handful of leaves tossed in after the sauce is cooled slightly may be all it takes.

Comment: @sjwarner Be sure to Google "Shandong sauce" there are variations, including some with soy and some with cilantro (and some with both). So far I'm unable to find one that specifies a particular chili beyond "red".

Comment: For fresh chilies I have used cayenne, Thai bird, and Fresno. I have also had similar, sometimes better, results using dried chilies. For dried I mostly use chili de arbol, but have also used cayenne and pequin with good results.

Comment: Many recipes call for hot chili oil - not to be added to the sauce but to pour over the chicken. While that doesn't appeal to me I have added 2 - 3 drops to the sauce while heating. This seems to add an extra layer of flavor that you almost can't identify. If you try this please only use a couple of drops as too much can totally overwhelm the other flavors.

Comment: Will do, thanks for your advice @Cindy. My first attempt will be with Pequins I think - I've found them to have a large range of flavour depending on how and how long you cook them.

Comment: Hi Cindy. I've had a couple of attempts at replicating this, and have tried incorporating elements of some other recipes I've found. It's still not *exactly* the same as the restaurant version, but a few more attempts should get it. Thank you! One thing I've yet to try is adding 'black vinegar'. Do you cook with it?

Comment: Hello @sjwarner. I have never used black vinegar. I would suggest experimenting to see how it comes out. Based on your description of the sauce I would also suggest trying some very light vinegar such as rice vinegar. No matter which vinegars you try, I would start with a small amount. You can always add more but you can't take it out :)